# How to Redirect Traffic If User Is In a Certain Directory and There is a Query String

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to redirect all traffic that has the directory /members/ and the query string ?loggedout=true to the homepage.

Here's an example:

https://thebestsites.com/members/brian/settings/?loggedout=true

This URL should redirect to the homepage. I'm looking to do this either using a WordPress plugin or Nginx... any ideas? Am I posting this in the right place?

This is not working:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name thebestsites.com *.thebestsites.com;
    return 301 https://thebestsites.com$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/thebestsites.com/cert/thebestsites.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/thebestsites.com/cert/thebestsites.com.key;

    server_name thebestsites.com   www.thebestsites.com;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/thebestsites.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/thebestsites.com.error.log;


    root /var/www/thebestsites.com/htdocs;

    location /members {
        if($arg_loggedout = true) {
            rewrite ^/members/  /  redirect;
        }
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    include common/wpfc-php7.conf;

    include common/wpcommon-php7.conf;
    include common/locations-php7.conf;
    include /var/www/thebestsites.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Sure, this is possible. Please post your nginx configuration so that we can provided an answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker doesn't know how to use **systemd** (see his comments).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do use [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx) for all your redirect needs!

```
if ($arg_loggedout = true) {
    rewrite ^/members/  /   redirect;
}
```

Comment: Can I make it so this if statement only fires when they're in the directory members?

Comment: #location /members/ {
    #    if($arg_loggedout = true) {
    #        rewrite ^/members/  /  redirect;
    #    }
    #}

Throwing an error that says "Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" f
or details."

Comment: yes, the if directive works within the location context, too; see http://nginx.org/r/if.  what error are you getting?  don't copy-paste the help on how to see the error-message details, copy-paste the error message itself! :-)

Comment: The error message is Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" f or details

Comment: again, that is not the error message.  nginx does not produce any messages that have any mention of "systemd".  if you don't know how to start nginx or get its error message, that is way beyond the scope of your original question (and, moreover, most certainly beyond the scope of StackOverflow, which is about programming, not system administration).

Comment: Also, I see you're putting this `if` within a `location` that is otherwise empty; that's not going to work, because only one location can ever be matched for any request (so, it'll either be this one, or the one from your include files).  you have to put it at the top-level within the server context.